# Linq Aggregate produces error: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. // Unhandled Expression Type: 1001"

Tags: linq, expression, aggregate, unhandled, method-invocation

The following line of code keeps crashing on me with: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. // Unhandled Expression Type: 1001"

Can anyone tell why just by looking at it?

```
myList.Aggregate((curmax, x) => (curmax == null || x.LastMonth > curmax.LastMonth ? x : curmax));
```

What i do get is that curmax is the variable that will be returned and that X is an item being iterated over. but i just can not explain the error.

Comment: What provider are you using? What is the type of `myList`?

Comment: myList contains a list of a class called: "Period".

I am using Linq to Nhibernate.

Comment: But it's not *actually* a `List<T>`, presumably? I suspect this is just something that NHibernate doesn't support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is just an operation which is unsupported by NHibernate. However, if you're just after "the value with the largest value for LastMonth" you could use:

```
var latestPeriod = myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastMonth)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

That would be considerably simpler, and more likely to be supported.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I added my own awser also.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling `.Tolist()` from Nhiberate. From there on the aggregate extension method from Microsoft Linq is used (in stead of the Nhibernate version) and no more problem.

```
myList.ToList().Aggregate((curmax, x) => (curmax == null || x.LastMonth > curmax.LastMonth ? x : curmax));
```

Comment: Are you aware that that means you're now pulling down *everything* in `myList` from the database? Does the solution I proposed not work? (It's rather more readable aside from anything else, IMO.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jon. At the time i wasn't aware of this.
Now... with a better knowledge of concrete classes vs IEnumerables i am. In our case pulling down everything wasn't that bad performance wise.